# CMOS (analog) switch output has a few hundred mV offset when output is disabled

Tags: cmos, analog-switch

I'm using an [TS12A4514](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts12a4514.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1638897194558&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fts12a4514) CMOS switch in order to isolate some digital lines from one device to another. Power rails are 5V & 0V (GND).

While the switch is enabled (enable input is 5V), input voltages both high and low register almost exactly the same on the output.

When the enable output is low (0V) the input is disconnected but I can see anywhere between 200mV to 600mV on the 'NO' terminal, regardless to what is connected to the 'COM' terminal.
I have tried driving the enable pins with a low voltage and with an actual short to GND with a wire, saw no difference.

Currently there is nothing connected to the 'NO' terminals so they are floating in the air. The power supply comes from an NIDAQ device and so are the enable control and digital input signals.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with the circuit? Shown here below:
The ICs are all decoupled with 100nF caps near them, not shown in the schematic.
[image]

Comment: What is connected to the NO outputs of the switches when you are measuring the low levels?

Comment: An NI USB-6009's digital output pin set to low voltage output.

Comment: The 5V supply is maintained? The 0.6V (assuming a 5V supply) implies a lot of current flowing, such as two outputs fighting.

Comment: @user733606 No, not the COM input...what is connected to the **NO output pin** of each switch.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Oh, MCU pins. The voltage supply of which is runs on a 3.33V battery. It does seem that there is some struggle going on between the outputs, but I am not sure why. When I disconnect everything from NO output pin I measure a voltage that is very close to the voltage on the COM port (around 0.04V) which is fine.

Comment: It's impossible to answer unless you actually edit your question and show/detail what's connected to those pins, as people have asked. (Please don't dump a few words at the end with an 'Edit' banner, put the information into the actual question.) Don't run a bit-at-a-time Comment chat, it's not a discussion forum. Thanks.

Comment: @user733606, sounds like you have configured your MCU wrong then. What is the voltage on the MCU pins, when it is disconnected from the NO output pin?

Comment: Is there any kind of load on all the NO outputs?  If not, then those outputs just float when the switch is not enabled and could read anything, drift around, etc.  If they are unloaded, try connecting a high value resistor, say 100 Kohms, between the output and GND.

Comment: @SteveSh No load at all, so you say this is caused by the combination of the very low leakage but high impedance at the output? When I connect a load, this should go away, correct? This could be an simple as a resistor or another device's input.

Comment: @user733606 - Yes, that would be my guess.  But another device's input may not work, if it has true CMOS inputs (very high impedance).  You need to place weak pull up or pull down resistors on those signals if you want them to be defined when all of the switches are disabled.

Comment: @SteveSh My goal with using the CMOS switches was to limit the leakage current that was drawn by the device that connects to the 'NO' terminals. I want to measure its leakage current and disconnect all the digital pins I am using to manipulate it.

Comment: Measuring input leakage current on modern CMOS devices is very tricky, since they are so low.  I don't even think most IC manufacturers do that on a production basis - those data sheet values are probably "guaranteed by design".  You should use the input leakage current from the data sheet of the devices the CMOS switches drive.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the diagram provided. With a -94db OFF isolation, and Vin=0.3V, then Vout should be just under 6uV.

Either you are testing with a defective part, or the diagram is not telling us the whole story. Suggest you prototype one known-good part and re-test your theory, then start reviewing your board to find out what is different. Possibly using wrong pins on package (none were in the diagram for us to check), or the output is connected to another output trying to drive high.

Comment: Pinout of the devices was checked and now I am trying to run with nothing connected to the 'NO' terminals.